# Problem with using "Alt" in lyx shortcuts (windows)

Tags: lyx

I'm having a problem when using ANY lyx shortcut that starts with "Alt +". Every time I press Alt (regardless of what other key I press simultaneously), the program automatically moves me to the drop-down menus (File, Edit, View, Insert, etc.) instead of triggering the shortcut sequence.

I have used Lyx for years, and this has never been an issue before. It started popping up on a new computer I am using for the first time (the OS is Windows 10 Enterprise, and I am on version 2.3.6.1 of Lyx).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try checking what happens in MS Notepad or MS word and the like. Maybe it is a question that you should ask on a Microsoft forum.

Comment: The same thing happens, but I'm pretty sure that was always true on my previous machines as well, and Lyx shortcuts used to work on those. I tried to figure out how to disable the Microsoft Alt shortcut altogether, but so far I haven't been able to find an easy fix for that either.  I'll post on a Microsoft forum as well to see if I get anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I figured it out. It turns out that there is some sort of conflicts in shortcuts with this Dell software I have installed on my computer (Dell Display Manager 2.0). Exiting that program restores full functionality to the Lyx shortcuts. Ugh.

Comment: Thanks for posting a self-answer, +1 and +1, in 48 hours or however long it is could you please accept your answer as "accepted" using the arrow next to your answer? It helps keep the site clean and stops the `community` bot from bumping this question every few months :)

Comment: Yep! I'll set a reminder to do that:)